# Сортировка. Нарушается порядок

Tags: c, алгоритм, сортировка

Есть массив из пар элементов (Priority:Sec)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я сортирую его, используя *quicksort*, по приоритетам:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Далее я прогоняю полученный сортированный массив снова в *quicksort*, но уже по SEC, планируя получить

```
(10:10)(100:10)(250:10)(200:11)(250:20)(100:21)(50:30)(50:31)
```

А получаю:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код:

```
// Быстрая сортика
    void quicksort(struct ProcessManager * PRMR, int first, int last, bool SEC){
        struct SimpleProcess count;
        int mid;
        int f=first, l=last;

        if (PRMR->RealCount < 2) return;

        if (SEC) mid=PRMR->Process[(f+l) / 2].SecurityLevel;
            else mid=PRMR->Process[(f+l) / 2].Priority; 

        do {
            if (SEC){
                while (PRMR->Process[f].SecurityLevel<mid) f++;
                while (PRMR->Process[l].SecurityLevel>mid) l--;
            } else {
                while (PRMR->Process[f].Priority<mid) f++;
                while (PRMR->Process[l].Priority>mid) l--;
            }
            if (f<=l) //перестановка элементов
            {
            count=PRMR->Process[f];
            PRMR->Process[f]=PRMR->Process[l];
            PRMR->Process[l]=count;
            f++;
            l--;
            }
        } while (f<l);

        if (first<l) quicksort(PRMR, first, l, SEC);
        if (f<last)  quicksort(PRMR, f, last, SEC);
    }

    // Сортировка диспетчера задач
    bool sort_procman(struct ProcessManager * PRMR){

        // Сортировка процесс менеджера
        if (PRMR->Sorted) return true;
        if (PRMR->RealCount <= 1) {PRMR->Sorted = true; return true;}

        // Сортировка по приоритету
        quicksort(PRMR, 0, PRMR->RealCount-1, false);

        // Сортировка по уровню безопасности
        quicksort(PRMR, 0, PRMR->RealCount-1, true);

        // Обновляем инфо
        PRMR->Sorted = true;
        return true;

    }
```

Вопрос: Почему так получается и как получить желаемое?

P.S. Сорри, что картинками - программа выполняется под MS-DOS

Comment: Забавно, что порядок приоритетов получается обратным

Comment: Используйте другую сортировку, которая не меняет порядок элементов. Тот же mergeSort. По скорости то же самое, но порядок поступления остается неизменным

Comment: if (f<=l) //перестановка элементов  а если убратьравно? Я хз как оно работает, но по логике не надо ничего менять, если они равны, так?

Comment: Ваша вторая сортировка полностью игнорирует результаты первой

Comment: Почитайте разницу между устойчивыми и неустойчивыми методами сортировки. Квиксорт как раз является неустойчивым. https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A3%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B9%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0

Comment: При чём тут вообще устойчивая сортировка если у автора алгоритм просто игнорирует на втором проходе первое поле? Никакая устойчивость не полечит пару (100,20) vs (200,10)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нужна только **одна** сортировка с правильной функцией сравнения, в которой должно в первую очередь сравниваться главное поле, а при его равенстве - вторичное (и т.д., если полей много).

В указанном примере главным полем будет второе, но  это можно переключать.
Примерно так работают сортировки элементов в проводнике Windows в табличном режиме показа - при выборе колонки "по типу" файлы будут группироваться по расширению, а в каждой группе  упорядочиваться по имени. При выборе колонки "по имени" - наоборот.

Comment: хз за что вас минусят, имхо - дело пишете, добавлю плюсик для баланса.